# How do I replace a regular expression with a newline in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I would like to put a newline after every tag in an HTML file in Emacs.
Now I have got

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \(<[^>]*>\) --> \1\n
```

This returns

```
invalid use of "\"
```

I've already tried `C-x C-j`, but that returns `<html>C-x C-j<head>C-x C-j etc...`

If anybody knows the solution, that would be helpful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of \n, use C-q C-j

http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/008872.html

Comment: nope, it returns the same as before, but now wirh q instead of x

Comment: By C-q I mean control-Q (hold down control and hit Q).  So control-Q control-J (with no space) should work.

Comment: oh, like that :), wait a sec, trying in progress... :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Could you accept my answer by clicking on the litlte checkmark next to your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 8):

You can use `C-q` to insert control characters.

`C-q C-j` to insert a newline, `C-q C-i` to insert a tabulator etc.

So instead of `\n` just type `C-q C-j`.

Comment: And `C-q C-j` is, of course, what user1009013 should have been using instead of `C-x C-j`. (Where ever you read that, it's wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct.  An additional caveat:  when trying match a whole line including newline, e.g. `^.*SOMETHING.*$`, *replace* the `$` with C-q C-j, do not append C-q C-j.  Unlike some other Regexp dialects, `$` plus newline (C-q C-j) does not match in emacs Regexp.